# Is it safe to migrate from composite PK to single PK like this

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a composite PK *(code_id, user_id)*, that already have 100k records. Is it safe to move from composite PK to a single PK like in the example below?

```
ALTER TABLE orders
  DROP CONSTRAINT pk_code_id_user_id,
  ADD COLUMN order_id SERIAL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_order_id PRIMARY KEY (order_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is safe and will work.

The only problem is that this statement can take a while to get done:

- all rows have to get updated with the `DEFAULT` sequence value
- a new unique index is built
- PostgreSQL checks that `order_id IS NOT NULL` for all rows

During that time, the table is locked in `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` mode, so it is not available even for concurrent reading.

But with a tiny table like that is should not be a big problem.

Things get more complicated if there are foreign key constraints that reference the old primary key constraint. You'd have to drop those as well and think of a good replacement.

Comment: Thanks, do compound index (code_id, user_id) will be dropped as well by pg or it remains after pk changes?

Comment: Yes. If you drop the constraint, the index that implements it is automatically dropped.